# C# XmlIgnoreAttribute similar property name

Tags: c#, xml

XmlIgnoreAttribute ignoring both property's  `IsEnabled` and `isEnabledFieldSpecified` bacause they have similar names. How to fix this problem? As result in i property `secondCar` i have `IsEnabled=false` but i expect to get `IsEnabled=true`. Maybe this is duplicate question but i can not find answer on stack.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car firstCar = new Car() { IsEnabled = true };
        Car secondCar = new Car() { IsEnabled = false };

        secondCar = XmlUtility.XmlStr2Obj<Car>(XmlUtility.Obj2XmlStr(firstCar));

    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Car
{
    private bool isEnabledFieldSpecified;

    private bool isEnabledField;

    [XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isEnabledField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isEnabledField = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool IsEnabledSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isEnabledFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isEnabledFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}

namespace Utils
{
    public class XmlUtility
    {
        public static string Obj2XmlStr(object obj, string nameSpace)
        {
            if (obj == null) return string.Empty;
            XmlSerializer sr = SerializerCache.GetSerializer(obj.GetType());

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter w = new StringWriter(sb, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            sr.Serialize(
                w,
                obj,
                new XmlSerializerNamespaces(
                new[]
                    {
                    new XmlQualifiedName("", nameSpace)
                    }
                ));
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static string Obj2XmlStr(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return string.Empty;
            XmlSerializer sr = SerializerCache.GetSerializer(obj.GetType());

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter w = new StringWriter(sb, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            sr.Serialize(
                w,
                obj,
                new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { new XmlQualifiedName(string.Empty) }));

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static T XmlStr2Obj<T>(string xml)
        {
            if (xml == null) return default(T);
            if (xml == string.Empty) return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlSerializer sr = SerializerCache.GetSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)sr.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        public static XmlElement XmlStr2XmlDom(string xml)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            return doc.DocumentElement;
        }

        public static XmlElement Obj2XmlDom(object obj, string nameSpace)
        {
            return XmlStr2XmlDom(Obj2XmlStr(obj, nameSpace));
        }
    }

    internal class SerializerCache
    {
        private static readonly Hashtable Hash = new Hashtable();
        public static XmlSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
        {
            XmlSerializer res;
            lock (Hash)
            {
                res = Hash[type.FullName] as XmlSerializer;
                if (res == null)
                {
                    res = new XmlSerializer(type);
                    Hash[type.FullName] = res;
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out `[XmlAttributeAttribute()]`?

Comment: @mjwills, if i comment [XmlAttributeAttribute()] in result i have IsEnabled=false.

Comment: @mjwills, try to rename IsEnabledSpecified to IsTEnabledSpecified. Without any attribute changes.

Comment: So you are saying if you rename it to `IsTEnabledSpecified` it works fine?

Comment: @mjwills, i think yes.

Comment: @mjwills, I sure. What's disturbing you in my code?

Answer (score -1):

Try to set IsEnabledSpecified property to true in both objects. Like this:

```
Car firstCar = new Car() { IsEnabled = true, IsEnabledSpecified  = true };
Car secondCar = new Car() { IsEnabled = false, IsEnabledSpecified  = true };
```

This way serializer would know, that isEnabled property should be serialized.
IsEnabledSpecified   property has special meaning to the serializer: it wouldn't be serialized itself(because of XmlIgnore attribute), but it controls would xml element it related to appear("Specified" property set to true) in the xml payload or not("Specified" property set to false).